# Explicit authentication in SSO

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

**Scenario:**
We have a web application deployed on a cloud. This application uses the SSO (Idp-initiated) set up of the client. Things are working fine. The user once log on to their corporate network, can use our application without putting in their credentials.

**Understanding of SSO:**
SSO aims at managing the identities centrally, against each corporate application taking credential as input and authenticating the user. This results in trust as user does not enter username/password for using an application.

**Note About E-Signature:**
This, not to be confused by Digital signature. This is very critical requirement for Pharma domain software. If a user is performing some important action e.g. approving etc, then she has to enter her credentials explicitly before that action could be carried out, even when the user is already logged in and has session. The objective of this is to prevent misuse of an open terminal.

**Problem:**
For an application under SSO, **is there any way for explicit authentication as required by E-Signature**?

Please note that, our application can always send a SAML request to check whether a user is authorized or not, but it happens without the password and its not an explicit authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about [ForceAuthn](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) (page 49, line 2042):

**ForceAuthn** [Optional]:
A Boolean value. If "true", the identity provider MUST authenticate the presenter directly rather than rely on a previous security context. If a value is not provided, the default is "false". However, if both ForceAuthn and IsPassive are "true", the identity provider MUST NOT freshly authenticate the presenter unless the constraints of IsPassive can be met

Answer (score -1):

Gravedigging an old thread... the problem seems to be that not all providers will force interactive authentication with ForceAuthn -- as long as they are not relying on previous security context, they are "complying" with the spec.  But that means that if you're not signed in at all and therefore have no previous security context to rely on, you can come in with a ForceAuthn request and the IDP will use whatever desktop single sign on solution they employ to happily grant you a new session (i.e. new security context) and pass you back to the SP without having to manually/actively interact with the IDP.